# Pentaho Data Integration (PDI): Inserting Boolean values from source to target

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

Having trouble creating a simple source to target transformation. Source and target Database is Postgresql. Source has boolean values which I need to load into my target table.

ERROR: column "column name" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying.

When I check the data the values are only either "TRUE" or "FALSE". Values cannot be text as the datatypes defined in the database for the columns is boolean. I don't quite understand how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of PDI has an option "Supports boolean data type" under "Advance" tab in the target database connection. Selecting option "Supports boolean data types" Should solve the problem.